# Free space in iCloud not less even after having deleted all files in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, storage, file

I have moved all the files located at "Documents" and "Desktop" folder to `/home/tmp` folder. Also I have deleted all the files in **icloud.com**, but whenever I check the iCloud Storage, it's still the same, not less.

1. I'm making sure all files on **icloud.com** and **local** has been 
   deleted.

   > [image]
2. Storage size by local (MacBook):

   > [image]
3. Storage size by icloud.com :

   > [image]

[image: System Preferences]

Any ideas?

I try to contact Apple Support, but their website always come with :

> **We’re sorry, there are no solutions available at the moment. Please try again later.**

Comment: It appears some apps have documents stored in iCloud Drive. Click on the Manage... button to see what apps are taking up how much storage.

Comment: Possibly iCloud backups from an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: How are you checking icloud size?

Comment: @jmh i check both, in my macbook and icloud.com. i see in icloud.com files become active again, although i have deleted all files in my macbook's document & desktop

Comment: @SteveChambers no, i have check both. all have deleted, except at icloud.com

Comment: @anunixercoder **1.** Please go to iCloud Drive in Finder and see what is there. Is there something(even videos) that take up that storage? **2.** Go to iCloud preferences on Mac and see if Desktop and Documents is turned on or not.

Comment: Did you empty trash after deleting files from the icloud drive?

Comment: @jmh yes, of course. i try to contact apple support. but their web always come with `We’re sorry, there are no solutions available at the moment. Please try again later.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this issue, by choose **"Delete Documents and Data"** at my iPhone's iCloud setting :

[image: icloud drive setting]

now my `iCloud` drive size is decreased :

[image: icloud image size]

Answer (score 3):

open system preferences and click on icloud. a new panel opens as shown below. click on the option button next to icloud.

[image]

After clicking the Option button a new panel opens. At the bottom of that panel is a checkbox to optimize mac storage. Make sure that box is unchecked.  See 2nd figure below.

[image]

If the new icloud space doesn't look correct give it a few hours to update.

Comment: I have tried this yesterday, but as today still not solving issue

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem and I found the same problem as you. I tried turning off iCloud and that did the trick.  I don't know if I lost anything by turning off I cloud.  So far all seems intact but that was only thirty minutes ago.  When you turn off I cloud it gives you a message box but I didn't read it carefully. Sorry.

Comment: after a few seconds, I turned iCloud back on but my icloud drive is still showing empty.

Comment: @jmh was it this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBXW8.png

Comment: yes, that's it.  Turning off icloud worked for me.